# In shell, what does "./directory" command means?

Tags: shell, busybox, adb

I'm trying to install busybox on my tab.
I copied the busybox binaries to my tab,
went to its location,
then printed "./busybox", enter.
message appeared:
"can't execute: is a directory"
It looks like the shell searched for a valid binary in directory to execute and found nothing, maybe my tab needs a specific binary architect that doesn't exist in busybox folder! but I haven't any proof.
thank you for reading and helping!

Answer (score 3):

No, the shell didn't look for a valid binary in directory to execute and found nothing. It simply tried to execute the directory. Apparently, that's not the way to go.

Sometimes, in some shells (for example bash with `autocd` shopt set), executing a directory results in opening it, or setting it as the working directory. Still, however, if you want to execute a file within it, you need to give the command explicitly. Thus if there's any script in `./directory`, you need to either:

- move to that directory

  ```
  cd directory
  ```

  and then execute the executable:

  ```
  ./executable
  ```
- or execute it from where you are now without moving first, eg.

  ```
  directory/executable
  ```